# How to un-set a property in a CSS pseudo-class?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have CSS like this

```css
*:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid blue; /* This value is dynamically set based on configuration */
}
```

I now have a button with class `toggle` that has

```css
.toggle {
  /* ... many other styles */
  outline: none;
}
```

This `outline: none` is to prevent the default focus outline from showing when the button is clicked. However, I'd now like the `focus-visible` style defined above to apply to it, since `focus-visible` styles are only applied in more specific cases, when the focus really should be visible, not just when the button is clicked.

I half expected something like this to work:

```css
.toggle:focus-visible {
  outline: inherit;
}
```

But if I understand this correctly, `inherit` does not mean it's inheriting the value from the parent's `focus-visible` styles. Is there any way to do this without the `.toggle` styles having to duplicate the value set earlier? In other words, is there some way to have it "fall back"?

Comment: Another option would be to set `outline: none` with a selector like `.toggle:not(:focus-visible)`, instead of resetting the value.

Comment: Ooh, I like that idea. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Or `outline: unset;` ?

Comment: Nope, unset sets it to the browser's default value. @DarrylNoakes's solution worked though. Daryl, if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way (AFAIK) to *reset* a value to what was set in another, certain ruleset.

Instead setting it to `none` by default for `.toggle` and then "resetting" it to the "active" value on a certain state, you can clear it only when it is not in that state.

This can be done by setting `outline: none` with a selector like `.toggle:not(:focus-visible)`.

The code will explain better than I can:

```css
/* As before */
*:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}

/* Do not set it at all here. */
.toggle {
  /* outline: none; */
}

/* Remove the outline only when it is not :focus-visible. */
.toggle:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}
```

This has a distinct benefit over the other approaches: users with browsers that do not support `:focus-visible` will get their browser's default focus ring, instead of nothing — because the last ruleset is dropped due to an unsupported/unrecognized and therefore "invalid" pseudo-class.

---

Another option would be to use a [CSS custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (AKA CSS variable) to hold the initial, default value. This would of course require that you can configure the the configuration system to set this custom property instead of `outline` directly.
Then you could do something like this:

```css
/* Set a CSS var here instead of `outline`. */
*:focus-visible {
  --outline: 2px solid blue;
}

/* Use the outline if specified, else none. */
.toggle {
  outline: var(--outline, none);
}
```

This defaults to using `none`, but will use the value of the `--outline` var if it is defined.

A possible downside to the basic approach is that *everything* that relied on the outline being set would now have to set it from `--outline`. Instead, you can set the `outline` property as well: "naive" elements will just use it, but any that need it can be customized (such as buttons). As follows:

```css
*:focus-visible {
  --outline: 2px solid blue;
  outline: var(--outline); /* This is new */
}

.toggle {
  outline: var(--outline, none);
}
```

This approach does unfortunately force `outline` to `none` unless `--outline` is set, so it disables default outline behavior, such as the browser's focus indicator.

---

A last-ditch option: use `!important` in the `*:focus-visible` rule, like so:

```css
*:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid blue !important;
}
```

This should be avoided if at all possible, because `!important` makes things complicated and harder to maintain and modify in the long run. But sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do (although it usually means there are flaws somewhere in the system).